# I can't see half of the map in Candy Box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I can only see up to right before the well. I switch between iPad and computer because I play at school and at home, and this only happens on my iPad.

[image: Candy Box 2 map]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? What do you mean with "this only happens on my iPad"?

Comment: I switch between Ipad and computer because i play at school and at home. The photo is here. https://ibb.co/T0HztNQ